# Reason why IPv6 IP adresses have a size of 128 bits and not 256?

Tags: network-protocols, ipv6

I was discussing with a friend about some internals of IPv6.

It is well-known that IPv6 IP adresses have a size of 128 bits (for IPv4 it is 32 bits).

He asked me what is the reason why this size was set to 128 bits - 256 bits would have made a more "well-rounded" size and both sizes should by far be large enough to avoid any lack of IP adresses in the future.

I assumed that it has to do that on embedded devices like routers you have to be a lot more careful of memory requirements and 128 was the least power of two such that you surely don't run out of IP adresses of this size in the future.

But I had to admit not to know a clear answer.

So, network wizards, what is the reason why 128 bits were chosen as size of an IPv6 adress and not 256?

Comment: 128 bit is enough for IP addesses for like forever!

Comment: If "both sizes should by far be large enough to avoid any lack of IP adresses in the future", then why would you go for the largest one? How is 256 bits more "well rounded" than 128? They are both equal to a round number of bytes.

Comment: @Lâm Tran Duy Who knows what applications you could find in the future?

Comment: @Nubok true, but then why stop at 256? A 1024 bits size could open even more possibilities... but realistically, it's already going to be quite hard to find a use for 2^128 IP adresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPv6 was known during its development as "IPng" (IP Next Generation), and was an IETF effort in mid-1990s.  There were actually several proposed successors to IPv4, and after some period of testing, debate, and analysis, then final candidate IPng was actually a compromise between a 64 bit solution (SIPP) and a variable-length (but 128 bit default) solution (TUBA).  The compromise roughly made use of the longer address format, but fixed the length at 128 bits.

RFC 1752, "The Recommendation for the IP Next Generation Protocol" would be a good reference for those interested in more information.

/John

Comment: Just to be clear they weren't "successors" per se as ipv4 was never intended for widespread use.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect because there's really no point in having them be bigger than 128 bits.

Remember that every bit/byte in the address needs to be included in the header. In other words, the bigger the address, the bigger the overhead on the network.

Answer (score 4):

According to [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-ipv6.html), 128 bits will give approximately 6.67 * 10^27 IPv6 addresses per square meter on our planet. It is hard to think that will ever be insufficient.

Comment: What about the extra terrestrial population? (i.e. the colonies  from Mars). They will surely carry more devices on them.

Answer (score 1):

Reason #1: Absolutely no point for using 256bit addresses.
Reason #2: Those extra bits would have to be transmitted with every single packet header passing thought the net. That would be at least some terabytes of extra load over the Internet.

I 've been wondering why they didn't design for 64bit addresses. That would be still more than enough forever even if every device on earth and our solar system needed an IP address simultaneously.

2^64 is around 18,000,000,000,000,000 addresses.
That's more than enough for the next millenia.
And less bits means higher speeds and reduced costs.